# Script - Print out commands also

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to use the `script` command to run some tests on a `C` program I wrote and save the shell history to a file.

The problem I'm facing is that the resulting file does not show the actual commands, it only shows the outputs...

I'm currently using :

```bsh
$ script -c `./tests.sh` shell.txt
```

Where `tests.sh` is a bash script containing tests.

But that only writes what should appear on the standard output (similar as if I'd used a `>` redirection...

Do you know what I'm doing wrong, or if I've misread a man page ?

Cheers

Comment: Try skipping the backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `script -c "bash -v ./tests.sh" shell.txt`.

The `-v` flag ensures that commands are displayed while `./tests.sh` is executed.

Alternatively, I believe you could add `set -x` at the beginning of `./tests.sh` and add `set +x` at the end. However, this approach would always echo commands as they are executed any time `./tests.sh` is run.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks